# How can I set up a Dropdown List using Template Composer Annotation in Hippo CMS?

Tags: annotations, hippocms

Currently working on a simple component and I need the drop down to have a display name of :

> One, Three, and Five

However, I need that value to actually equal the integer value of these display names. One =  (int) 1, Three =  (int) 3, Five  =  (int) 5.

```
package com.authx.components;

import org.hippoecm.hst.core.parameters.DropDownList;
import org.hippoecm.hst.core.parameters.Parameter;

public interface PressEventComponentInfo {

    @Parameter(name = "number", required = true, displayName = "Release Number",       defaultValue="three")
    @DropDownList({"one", "three", "five"})
    String getNumber();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using i18n for property values.

For a dropdown field you can use the parameter name followed by a slash and then the parameter value again as the key (e.g. in your example, 'number/1=One').

```
+ site
    + src
        + main
            + java
            |   +com.authx.components.PressEventComponentInfo
            + resources
                +com.authx.components
                    - PressEventComponentInfo.properties
```

You can find more information about this subject and some examples on the [HST Component Parameters documentation page](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/component-development/hstcomponent-parametersinfo-annotation.html) and the [channel info page](http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/channels/additional-channel-information.html).

And adding the following properties:

```
number/1=One
number/3=Three
number/5=Five
```